# Vertically centering text within a div

Tags: css, positioning, centering

I am having a lot of trouble centering the text in the below div vertically. I'd appreciate it if someone can help me accomplish this.

This is what I tried:

```
<div class="input-label" style="vertical-align:middle;">Toys:</div>
```

This is my current markup:

```
<div class="input-label" >Toys:</div>
```

CSS

```
.input-label
{
   background-color:#7a86d0; 
   height:30px; 
   float:left; 
   width:130px; 
   text-align:right; 
   font-weight:bold; 
   padding-right:10px; 
}
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Try adding `line-height: 30px;`

Comment: Don't use `div.input-label`. Simply use the `<label>` tag.

Comment: @Torr3nt thanks for the reply! post your comment as an answer so I can mark as solution;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `line-height: 30px;` to your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

In the div style, insert a "display: table-cell;" before the vertical-align.